# How come this user has a lot more attack power with worse equipment?

Tags: mafia-wars-2

I have 2 boosts, a better weapon, but he's still a lot better in every status available. Yeah, he has better car, but it really isn't +92. He has still every status possible a lot higher than mine (besides critical).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last patch has unlocked all the equipment slots. He most likely has an item in every one of these slots by now. I am 39 right now and my attack/defense are both over 300 with just normal equipment (i.e. not purchased with gold bars).

I am not sure exactly what determines the type of vehicle/armor/weapon to show on the combat results page. It doesn't seem to be either the highest defence or the highest attack. Just keep this in mind. Appearance could be deceiving.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

My Profile: 
[image]

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Currenty, SMG compact is worse (in att, better in def) than my 1911 Subcompact. Additionally, I can't seem to buy any special weapons for money (only for gold). Where have you found the special weapon? How did you do such great att & def power?

Comment: From the Dead End. You know the limited time Arena? In general it's all about managing money. Try not to level up too quickly or you will never have enough money to replace your equipment quickly enough; have as many friends as you can so you can place all 15 workers; be active.

Comment: I have all workers possible :)

Comment: Then it's just a matter of waiting for the money to be generated and buy weapons. The Scythe (the special weapon) requires 400 Dead End tokens, so you'd have to fight people there to get them.

Comment: yeah, I'm waiting for that.